# How to get the web element value to a string variable using C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver, input

I need to read input value of an element and save it to a string variable 
in my c# windows form application. Is it possible?
Here is how I find the element:

```
IWebElement SearchCounter = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("counter"));
```

and here is the html code of the element:

```
<div id="page-content"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="counter" value="355">
```

If it's not possible to get the value, how can I read this element html source and assign it to a string variable in my app?

I don't get any result using this:

```
string cs = SearchCounter.GetAttribute("innerHtml");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get input value - you should use

`string cs = SearchCounter.GetAttribute("value");` instead of GetAttribute("innerHTML");

If you want to retrieve html source of an element, use innerHtml.

`Browser.FindElement(By.Id("page-content").GetAttribute("innerHTML")` would return `<input type="hidden" id="counter" value="355">` and SearchCounter.GetAttribute("innerHTML") would return something that's inside input.

Good luck!

Comment: I will try this method too Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To read the value of the `value` attribute, `GetAttribute` should be what you're looking for. For example, to get "Norway" out of that demo page, you'd use the following code: https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("iframeResult")));
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("country"));

var value = element.GetAttribute("value");
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

To your second question, the `driver.PageSource` property gives you the HTML of the current page. You would have to process that yourself then, of course.

```
var source = driver.PageSource;
Console.WriteLine(source);
```

Comment: you're welcome! if you'd accept/upvote the answers that were helpful for your, that would be nice :-)